# Exchange server mail interceptor (connector/delivery agents/mailflow)

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

My basic requirement is that I need to create "something" that is capable of intercepting emails incoming/outgoing from our mail server. It cannot be an extension to mail clients. Currently we consider only exchange server. In my research I found below resources that seems to be helpful.

- [Mail flow and the transport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/mail-flow?view=exchserver-2019)
- [Delivery agents and Delivery Agent connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/delivery-agents-and-delivery-agent-connectors-exchange-2013-help)
- [Transport agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/transport-agents-exchange-2013-help)

From these transport agents seems to be quite old. Now I can't figure out what's the best from the remaining options([Mail flow and the transport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/mail-flow?view=exchserver-2019) or [Delivery agents and Delivery Agent connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/delivery-agents-and-delivery-agent-connectors-exchange-2013-help)).

Whatever I develop should be able to read email get some statistics (using mail header(s), amount of attachments etc...) and store it into a custom database. Additionally add some custom headers to incoming/outgoing mails.

Can anyone point me to right direction? Should it be some kind of a service that I can install in Exchange server? (admin center->mail flow-> connectors). For example, can I write it in c# and host it like an assembly? or may be a web hook to a hosted service where Exchange will forward emails in real time etc...

I couldn't find any examples/tutorials except [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-api/aa564119(v=exchg.150))

Answer (score 0):

If its OnPrem Exchange and you don't have or are considering Office365 then Transport Agents would be the right thing to use. They haven't change since 2013 but are still what is used for this type of thing the last SDK was 2010 but its still valid given the lack of change on the backend https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd877026(v=exchg.140)

Delivery Agents are more for when you have an external gateway that you want to send and receive messages from.

Comment: we are already on O365. So I guess I should use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-server-development this content related to development i suppose?

Comment: If its O365 you need to look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/use-connectors-to-configure-mail-flow/integrate-office-365-with-an-email-add-on-service and basically create your own gateway service